# Problem with connect to mongoDB use tls certifications

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, ssl

I have a problem with connection string to database.  
I have a server with mongodb, who are configure to connect with tls.

My connection string look  like: 
`mongodb://{mongodbusername}:{mongodbpassword}@{mongodburi}:27017/someDatabase?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=admin&tls=true&tlsCAFile=<path>/rootCA.pem&tlsCertificateKeyFile=<path>/mongodb.pem&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true&tls=true`

During starting program, he is transfrom to: 
`mongodb://username:password@url:27017/someDB?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=admin&tls=true&tlsCAFile=C:/certs/rootCA.pem&tlsCertificateKeyFile=C:/certs/mongodb.pem&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true&tls=true`

I try path like C:\certs\ too.

Trying connect to database I get error like this: 
**Message=A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/path:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/path:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot**

When I try connect to mongoDB instance via mongodb compass with this same credential and that same certs, everythink are ok and I will be connected do instance.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

.net driver doesn't support providing certificates via connection string.
To provide a client certificate, you need to use ClientCertificates [list](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_SslSettings_ClientCertificates.htm) in SslSettings.
As for CA certificate, you only can configure it on OS level. For windows, it can be done via `certutil`:

```
certutil.exe -addstore "Root" <path_to_ca_cert>
```

Also, a client certificate should be in `.p12` format, not `.pem`. To convert pem certificate into p12, you can use `openssl`:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in "${CLIENT_PEM}" -out "${X509_CLIENT_P12}" \
-name "Client Certificate" \
-password "pass:${X509_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD}"
```