# Connection string of MongoDB using TLS

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, connection, tls1.2

I am a DBA. I have one setup of TLS mechanism based environment. Want to connect that DB using C# drivers of application. I am unable to connect the same. sharing the connection string for the same below. can some one help into that connectivity.

**"mongodb://user:pass@hostname1:port,hostname2:port,hostname3:port/ibmclouddb?authSource=admin&replicaSet=replset&tls=true&tlsCAFile=/apps/Deploy/mongo/certificats/mg002i000589.pem"**

Conf of TLS

[image]

Comment: see my answer on similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518922/problem-with-connect-to-mongodb-use-tls-certifications/73519205#73519205

Comment: But what if DB servers are on IBM MongoDB services and certificates are also generated by IBM only.

Comment: and? It sounds like you still have a path to the certificate?

Comment: Yes CA certificate is already present. do we require to create client based CA certificate...

Comment: if you need specifying only CA certificate, then you should not doing anything in the driver with this certificate, you should register this certificate on machine if it's not already registered

Comment: mongo "mongodb://user:pass@hostname1:port,hostname2:port,hostname3:port/ibmclouddb?authSource=admin&replicaSet=replset&tls=true&tlsCAFile=/apps/Deploy/mongo/certificats/mg002i000589.pem" --shell by using this we are able to connect the DB using shell but from same server not able to connect application through above mentioned connection string. whats missing in connection string.

Comment: .net driver doesn't support `tlsCAFile` option- so you can't use this connection string there and instead should use a workaround I mentioned in the above link with `certutil.exe` to register CA cerificate

Comment: Its Mongo C# driver....

Comment: added configuration of TLS as well

Comment: .net and c# are the same in this context

Comment: configuration you provided in the screenshot doesn't match with options supported by mongo drives, but regardless: 1. if you need to configure CA certificate, you should do it on OS level 2. if you need a client certificate, then use `SslOption.ClientCertificate` in MongoClientSettings, but before convert pem, certificate to p12 (since pem is not supported too, see link below)

Comment: I meant link above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518922/problem-with-connect-to-mongodb-use-tls-certifications/73519205#73519205

Comment: You set `requireTLS`, so your connection string miss client certificate, i.e. `tlsCertificateKeyFile=....` parameter or according command option. Parameter `tlsCAFile=/apps/Deploy/mongo/certificats/mg002i000589.pem` is used to verify the server certificate `/conf/cert/tls.pem`

Comment: Its resolved by driver side of C# by writing additional code for TLS in connection string.