# Mongodb Attempted to read past the end of the stream

Tags: c#, linux, mongodb, runtime-error, mongodb-.net-driver

I was trying to connect to a local mongodb server using connectionuri

```
const string connectionUri1 = "mongodb://Mongodb:27123/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const string connectionUri2 = "mongodb://admin:password@Mongodb:27017/admin?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1";
const string connectionUri3 = "mongodb://Mongodb:27020/?authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&tls=true&tlsInsecure=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=/path/to/mongodbca.pem&tlsCAFile=/path/to/mongodbcli.pem&authSource=$external";

var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionUri3);
settings.ServerApi = new ServerApi(ServerApiVersion.V1);

// Create a new client and connect to the server
var client = new MongoClient(settings);

// Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
var result = client.GetDatabase("test").RunCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("ping", 1));
Console.WriteLine("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
Console.WriteLine("Reply: " + result);
```

connectionUri1 and 2 works just fine, I could ping and perform read or write
for connectionUri3, it produces timeouterror

```
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongodb:27020" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongodb:27020", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytes(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Dropbox.RemoveMessage(Int32 responseTo)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessage(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.Execute(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.Execute(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.HelloHelper.GetResult(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 helloProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.SendHello(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2023-10-30T21:05:52.9901869Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2023-10-30T21:05:52.9909228Z" }] }.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.IClusterExtensions.SelectServerAndPinIfNeeded(ICluster cluster, ICoreSessionHandle session, IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadPreferenceBinding.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadBindingHandle.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadContext.Initialize(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadContext.Create(IReadBinding binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.ReadCommandOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IReadBinding binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.ExecuteReadOperation[T](IClientSessionHandle session, IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.RunCommand[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, Command`1 command, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.<>c__DisplayClass50_0`1.<RunCommand>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.RunCommand[TResult](Command`1 command, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Program.Main() in /path/to/cs/mongodb_cs/Program.cs:line 29
```

I didnt even get through the ping with connectionUri3

I already checked with mongocompass with this connection string

```
mongodb://Mongodb:27020/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=D%3A%5Cca.pem&tlsCertificateKeyFile=D%3A%5Cmongodb.pem&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&authSource=%24external
```

and are able to connect just fine

I run both mongodb and the program in linux ubuntu

```
$ mongod --version
db version v7.0.2
Build Info: {
    "version": "7.0.2",
    "gitVersion": "02b3c655e1302209ef046da6ba3ef6749dd0b62a",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu2004",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I run the mongodb through service

```
$ sudo service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-10-31 03:52:38 KST; 2h 30min ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 944888 (mongod)
     Memory: 143.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─944888 /usr/bin/mongod --auth --tlsMode requireTLS --tlsCAFile /opt/mongodb/ssl/ca.pem --tlsCertificateKeyFile /opt/mongodb/ssl/mongodb.pem --config >
Oct 31 03:52:38 nw systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 31 03:52:38 nw mongod[944888]: /usr/bin/mongod: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/mongod)
Oct 31 03:52:38 nw mongod[944888]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-10-30T18:52:38.076Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":7484500, "ctx":"main","msg":"Environment variable MONGOD>
```

.NET Driver version

```
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.22.0" />
```

Comment: You are getting an error after 30 seconds.  Normally 30 seconds timeouts occur after a connection completes and query takes longer the 30 seconds to complete.  There is a timeout in the command which defaults to 30 seconds and increasing the command timeout usually solves this issue.  In this case I'm not sure if the connection completed.  You could have a TLS issue and the 30 seconds timeout may be occurring when the connection fails to complete.

Comment: TLS is performed before the request is sent to establish a secure connection between client and server.  I would change the command timeout to a longer period of time.  If you still get a 30 second timeout error than error is due to TLS.  If query works or error give different timeout than issue is not TLS and it is the default command timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing `tlsCertificateKeyFile` is not supported by .NET driver via connection string. You should register it via MongoClientSettings.SslSettings.ClientCertificates. See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/connection/tls/) for details.

`tlsCAFile` is not supported by .NET driver at all. You should register a CA certificate on OS level.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnt know its not supported by NET :” i just assumed they would work as its from the connection uri, which works for the gui and mongosh

Comment: The functionality itself is supported, but you just can't do it via connection string

Comment: i see, so basically the `tlsCAFile` is the responsibility of the user right? Since i cant set it up from my program. Do net receive client cert without password?

Comment: `i see, so basically the tlsCAFile is the responsibility of the user right?` - yes, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518922/problem-with-connect-to-mongodb-use-tls-certifications/73519205#73519205. `Do net receive client cert without password?` - I think so. See available ctors here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-7.0