Problem connecting to Mongo DB with TLS using connection string C#
I am trying to connect to MongoDB using a connection string and it fails. I am sure that the certificates that I have are correct because I can connect to the DB using this command in cmd:
mongo --tls --tlsCAFile D:\DEV\ca-valid.pem --tlsCertificateKeyFile D:\DEV\mongo-valid.pem --host localhost --port 27017 --username admin --password test --authenticationDatabase admin

However, when I try to connect from .net, I get this error:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-05-23T15:12:11.684+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn11603","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"no SSL certificate provided by peer; connection rejected"},"remote":"127.0.0.1:52931","connectionId":11603}}

this is the connection string that I am using:
mongodb://admin:test@localhost:27017/?tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=D%3A%5CDEV%5Cmongo-valid.pem&tlsCAFile=D%3A%5CDEV%5Cca-valid.pem&authSource=admin

I should mention that before enabling TLS I was able to connect to mongo DB using a connection string.
This is my mongod config file:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls:
   mode: requireTLS
   certificateKeyFile: D:\DEV\mongo-valid.pem
   CAFile: D:\DEV\ca-valid.pem

What is even more strange is that If I use MongoDB Compass I can connect to the database via a connection string that looks like this:
mongodb://localhost:27017/?tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=D%3A%5CDEV%5Cmongo-valid.pem&tlsCAFile=D%3A%5CDEV%5Cca-valid.pem

Any suggestions on what I can try next?

as we discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73519205/9492730. It's no possible to use connection string to configure SSL/TLS certificate in .net driver. Client certificate can be configured via MongoClientSettings, but CA only on OS level.

see here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4336

what would be another way to connect to the DB? I guess using MongoClientSettings and adding the certificate manually in there ?

yes for tlsCertificateKeyFile (clientcertificate)

tlsCAFile can be configured via OS configuration, see above link

What is the reason for --tlsCertificateKeyFile on the client side? I assume mongo-valid.pem is a server certificate, thus it does not make any sense to use it from the client. For the same reason you don't need tls.CAFile at the server configuration - assuming your run a stand-alone MongoDB instance. Of course, it is possible to use a client certificate without using it for x.509 authentication (unless you use MongoDB Atlas), but it does not make much sense.

As mentioned in the comments, the .NET/C# Driver does not support certificates by PEM files. Also as mentioned in my comment, it does not make much sense to use a client certificate, unless you like to use it for x.509 client authentication
You can try to import the CA ca-valid.pem into your Windows certificate store, see Adding Certificates to the Certificates Store on the Client. Then it might be possible (I did not test) to connect simply with this connection string
mongodb://localhost:27017/?tls=true

I assume the driver will use the CA from the certificate store by default.

already have done this and already tried this solution but it does not work
